pip installs very old version of Intel extension for tensorflow
I set up my computer with the recently released Ubuntu 24.04. I want to run notebooks in Jetbrains' Dataspell. For this purpose I installed tensorflow, notebook, and something called intel-extension-for-tensorflow. My HP machine does not have a classical graphics card, but it's sort of included on the CPU as far as I know and I want to be able to use it for my ML applications.
Global installations via pip are disabled since from Debian xx / Ubuntu 23.04. So I set up a virtual environment via python3 -m venv .venv, then source .venv/bin/activate. Then I installed the packages via: python3 -m pip install intel-extension-for-tensorflow[cpu] notebook. I expected tensorflow to be installed as a dependency of the intel extension, but it didn't. I'm given the warning intel-extension-for-tensorflow 0.0.0.dev1 does not provide the extra 'cpu and as you can see the real issue is that version 0.0.0-dev1 is being installed. I remember the intel extension would come with lots of other packages and when I subsequently installed tensorflow, the slightly older version that the intel-extension works with would be replaced by the newer one and vice versa if I would install the intel-extension via pip again.
python3 -m pip install intel-extension-for-tensorflow==2.15.0.0 gives ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement intel-extension-for-tensorflow==2.15.0.0 (from versions: 0.0.0.dev1). The --upgrade option also doesn't help. How can I resolve this?
Answer: Ubuntu 24.04 comes with Python 3.12 and there is no build yet of said package for this version.
